# Pass pointer to Collections Vector C++/cx

Tags: c++, windows, vector, uwp, c++-cx

In standard c++, I can make a vector, and modify the vector from another function like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void addnumber(vector<int> *testvec)
{
    testvec->push_back(4);
}
int main()
{
    vector <int> test;

    test.push_back(3);
    addnumber(&test);
    cout << test[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want to do this with a collections vector in C++/CX. The end goal for doing this is to bind the vector to a gridview control in UWP and have an async task modify it.

Comment: The best path is to look at the documentation and samples for uwp and c++-cx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below you will find a sample code for doing this. Actually async task should not modify vector that is bound to gridView - you should prepare new vector in worker thread and return it to UI thread and only then update vector bound to GridView.

What this code does is initialize vector with four values, then bind it to GridView, then create async task which will first wait 5s to allow to see those four values on screen, and after that time replace all values with one new.

```
void addnumber(Platform::Collections::Vector<int>^ testvec)
{
  testvec->Append(4);
}

Platform::Collections::Vector<int>^ vec = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<int>();

MainPage::MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

  addnumber(vec);
  addnumber(vec);
  addnumber(vec);
  addnumber(vec);

  gridView->ItemsSource = vec;

  Concurrency::create_task([]() ->Platform::Collections::Vector<int>^ {
    Concurrency::wait(5000);
    Platform::Collections::Vector<int>^ vec = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<int>();
    addnumber(vec); 
    return vec;
  }).then([](Platform::Collections::Vector<int>^ newVec) {
    vec->Clear();
    for (auto it : newVec)
      vec->Append(it);
  }, Concurrency::task_continuation_context::use_current());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It will still work if the Vector is declared inside a function like `MainPage::MainPage()` right?

Comment: Yes, but you would have to capture it in lambda. It would be better to mąke it a MainPage class field.